# NUnit causes WebException when using System.Net.WebClient

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit, webclient, mstest

The method below is working as intended when running through tests in *MS test* and through a Console application. When running it through a *NUnit* test I get an WebException.

Has any one else had this problem, and is there a way around it? It is not an option to use another testing framework.

```cs
public void Download(string username, string password, string dwlFileName, string dwlUrl)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization",
                              "Basic " +
                              Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));

        webClient.DownloadFile(dwlUrl, dwlFileName);
}
```

**Exception:**

```cs
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
       at TestProject.WebHelper.Download(String username, String password, String dwlFileName, String dwlUrl) in TestProject.WebHelper...
  InnerException: null
```

**Enviroment**

Visual Studio 2012

NUnit 2.6.3

***Any*** help would be much appreciated. Thanks! :)

**EDIT**
Have tried Nunit testrunner and resharpner test runner. Both fails.
I used wireshark to examine the the data sent. And found out there is one more call on the nunit test then the ms-test.

Comment: How do you run the NUnit test? Using VS, Resharper or Nunit test runner?

Comment: Can you disclose the URL (if its public)?

Comment: Good point with the testrunner. I use resharpner and our build server uses Nunit. I just tried running the tests in nunit, but it still fails. I cant publish the url. Do not belive there is a problem with the URL since everything works as intended outside nunit/resharpner environment.

Comment: Oh wait, this URl I can actually publish! Sorry. Here it is  https://datafeeds.networkrail.co.uk/ntrod/CifFileAuthenticate?type=CIF_ALL_FULL_DAILY&day=toc-full

Comment: Documentation from the provider: http://nrodwiki.rockshore.net/index.php/SCHEDULE

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect the traffic, it can decrypt HTTPS traffic.

Comment: The credentials seems to be the same. The only difference is in the webClient.DownloadFile request, where it somehow mess up the signature? Fiddle had following server response: SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Answer (score 0):

Until you answer the question, one thing to keep in mind is that the actual test runs under the process of the test runner. If the runner has some issues/restrictions those might interfere probably.

Do you have multiple tests that try to access that URL? In that case the server might have some security policies and will drop requests that might consider to be Denial of Service(too similar that come in too often).

Try adding a user agent header: `webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Other");`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the tests are able to run in Console and through ms test. Yes, i run multible tests accessing it, but this is only a problem for nunit, and not ms test. I have stress tested the server and have not encountered at security problem. It fails at first access to the server.

Comment: Added webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Other"); But it's still failing.